# change an item at specific column and row using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am able to print and change data on a column or row in a csv file using awk command. But how can I change data at a particular column-row combination?

For example at 3rd column on 2nd row:

```
NAME,AGE,ID,SCHOOL
ABC,20,4545,DGDG
NRG,23,6767,BDBD
DGE.21,5858,FRFR
```

I want to change 6767 to 0000.

## Can't figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the third record (row; header is the first record, so you have to add 1) and edit the third field (column):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==3 {$3="0000"}1' data.txt
NAME,AGE,ID,SCHOOL
ABC,20,4545,DGDG
NRG,23,0000,BDBD
DGE.21,5858,FRFR
```

Comment: Thanks

print is working fine : awk -F, 'NR==2{print $1}' file.csv

but updation is not working : awk -F, 'NR==2{$1="ABCD"}' file.csv

Comment: You forgot `-vOFS=,`. It sets the field separator for outputting records. And `1` on the end is important as well, otherwise nothing will get printed. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-an-awk-script

Comment: Actually, the command is printing the expected result without -v0FS=, and 1. The issue is when I am trying to update the field.

Comment: Show the exact command you're using to update the field.

Comment: awk -F, 'NR==2{$1=="0000"}' file.csv      
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==2{$1=="0000"}' file.csv

both not working

Comment: You forgot to add `1` at the end and used `==` in an assignment, where you have to use a single `=`.

Comment: sorry am using "=" there. typo. and could you please explain why 1 is needed? I am trying to edit on 2nd row(count includes the header).

Comment: See the link I pasted earlier. Basically, it tells Awk to print each line it processes.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  Now I want to change 2 data; 1st and 2nd column of the 2nd row. When I am running the commands one after another (first for 1st column, second for 2nd column), I noticed the 1st change gets reverted after running the second change. Can I change both in one command? if yes, please suggest how.

Comment: `NR==2 {$1="foo"; $2="bar"}1`

Comment: Thanks again
Now I want the "Bar" to be entered as an argument like this. test.sh \"hello\". I want "hello" as a data in the csv with double quote. Currently I am using line this NR==2 {$1="echo $1"; $2="echo $"}1 , but something is not right. want to pass two arguments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script/19075707#19075707

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==3{$3="0000"} 1' data.csv > data2.csv
```